# Extract some elements from vector based on condition

Tags: r

input vector would be

```
in <- c("Aone1","BZtwo2","AZtwenty4Btwo5","Cthirty22HIfour9")
```

I need the final output as

```
out <- c("one","two","twenty","two","thirty","four")
```

Extraction is based on lowercase letters between uppercase letters and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to extract the lower-case portions of the string? If so, just try:

```
v1 <- c("Aone1", "BZtwo2", "AZtwenty4Btwo5", "Cthirty22HIfour9")
regmatches(v1, gregexpr("[a-z]+", v1))
# [[1]]
# [1] "one"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "two"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "twenty" "two"   
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "thirty" "four"
```

Wrap the above in `unlist()` if you want to get a single character vector instead of a `list`.

Comment: thanks, the code is short and simple.  But, elements like "CZtwenty48two" will also extract "two", that is not needed.